# Drupal 7 - entityFieldQuery Order

Tags: drupal-7

Morning, im trying to get a set of latest node types but cant seem to figure out how to order them by date. Heres my function so far:

```
function latest_nodes($type, $limit = 15, $offset = 0) {
    $query = new EntityFieldQuery();
    $tmp = $query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node');
    if( is_string( $type ) )
        $tmp->entityCondition('bundle', $type);
    elseif( is_array( $type ) )
        $tmp->entityCondition('bundle', $type, 'IN');
    $tmp->range($offset, $limit);
    $results = $tmp->execute();
    return node_load_multiple(array_keys($results['node']));
}
```

any help would be muchly appreciated!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You're looking for the [`fieldOrderBy()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21entity.inc/function/EntityFieldQuery%3A%3AfieldOrderBy/7) member function, e.g.

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();
$query->fieldOrderBy('field_name_of_field', 'value', 'DESC');
```

Comment: Wow. The second parameter is literally `value`. That was surprisingly difficult to find, and seems like the most common use case.

Comment: @JonSurrell Technically the second parameter is the column name, which in most cases defaults to value

Answer (score 23):

You might be looking for [propertyOrderBy](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!entity.inc/function/EntityFieldQuery%3a%3apropertyOrderBy/7)

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();
$query->propertyOrderBy('changed', 'DESC');
```

Comment: use `->range(0,15);` to limit to 15 nodes.

Answer (score 0):

**to retrieve the latest post you can use**

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();
$entities = $query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
                  ->entityCondition('bundle', 'your_content_type')
                  ->propertyCondition('status', 1)
                  ->propertyOrderBy('created', 'DESC');
```